# how to set the last (lowest) 0 bit to 1

Tags: algorithm, bit-manipulation

we all know the trick n&(n-1) to set the last 1 bit to 0. e.g., 0110 & (0110-1) = 0100. but how about the reverse? set last 0 to 1? so 0110 becomes 0111?

I've done a great amount of search in stackoverflow and online. no result shows up

Comment: Not bit manipulation, but you could do `x >= 0 ? (x - x % 2) : (x + x % 2)`. If x is unsigned, then you can just do `x - x % 2`.

Comment: bitwise or with one: `x = x | 1` ... sorry, see my answer, i thought you want to just set the rightmost bit to one.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just do the opposite (well, not exactly but you get what I mean): `n | (n+1)`

Answer (score 1):

To set the last zero bit to one, you can add one to it and then bitwise or with itself

`(x + 1) | x`

Answer (score 0):

For setting a `k`th bit of the number just do the following operation

```
n=n|(1<< k)
```

where `k` is the bit you want to set.

I hope this helps.

For other bit manipulation, you can refer to this question: [Manipulation of bits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47981/how-do-you-set-clear-and-toggle-a-single-bit-in-c-c)

Comment: @vivek-pratap-chaurasia : Your answer refers to "setting a specific bit of x to 1". But the question is "setting the **last zero bit** to 1", without first finding which bit to set. Therefore, "101" (5) should become "111" (7) after the operation.

Answer (score 0):

For those who, like me, were looking for how to set *lowermost* zero bit, here's possible solution:

```
((((x-1) ^ x) & x) >>> 1) | x
```

For example, the lowermost zero bit of a number `101100` is the 3rd bit.

Let's break down the process of setting the lowermost bit:

- Minus `1` and XOR to get the mask: (x-1) ^ x (`101011` ^ `101100`) = `000111`
- AND the mask with the number to get the position of the first non-zero bit: `000111` & `101100` = `000100`
- Shift right to the lowermost zero bit position: `000100` >>> 1 = `000010`
- OR to set the bit: `101100` | `000010` = `101110`

UPD:

Alternative, and slightly more efficient solution is:

`(x & -x) >>> 1 | x`,

where `-x` is optimized version of `~(x-1)`.

Answer (score -1):

To set the last (lowest) 0 bit to 1:

```
x|1
```

Comment: @fei-hsueh: Your answer refers to "setting the last bit of x to 1". But the question is "setting the **last zero bit** to 1". Therefore, "101" (5) should become "111" (7) after the operation.